# The getter 'hour' was called on null

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I am trying to resolve this problem for last couple of days. Could not resolve this. This is a simple chat app where i am trying to just experiment. So when i send any message then this error shows and immediately goes away. Everything else is working fine. even retrieving the messages and sending the message also working fine. Just shows the error between retrieving the message and sending the message. Can anyone explain me why i am getting this error?
My code is here:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flash_chat/constants.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

final _fireStore = Firestore.instance;
final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
FirebaseUser loggedInUser;

class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static String id = 'chat_screen';

  @override
  _ChatScreenState createState() => _ChatScreenState();
}

class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {
  final messageTextController = TextEditingController();
  String messageText;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCurrentUser();
  }

  void getCurrentUser() async {
    try {
      final user = await _auth.currentUser();
      if (user != null) {
        loggedInUser = user;
        print(loggedInUser.email);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: null,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.close),
              onPressed: () {
                _auth.signOut();
                Navigator.pop(context);
              }),
        ],
        title: Text('⚡️Chat'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: MessageStream(),
            ),
            Container(
              decoration: kMessageContainerDecoration,
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: messageTextController,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        messageText = value;
                      },
                      decoration: kMessageTextFieldDecoration,
                    ),
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      messageTextController.clear();
                      final fieldValue = FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
                      await _fireStore.collection('messages').add({
                        "sender": loggedInUser.email,
                        "text": messageText,
                        "messageTime": fieldValue,
                      });
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'Send',
                      style: kSendButtonTextStyle,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MessageStream extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Timestamp serverTime;

    //var timeDate;

    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _fireStore
          .collection('messages')
          .orderBy('messageTime', descending: false)
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.data == null) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            ),
          );
        } else {
          final messages = snapshot.data.documents.reversed;
          List<MessageBubble> messageBubbles = [];
          for (var message in messages) {
            final messageText = message.data['text'];
            final sender = message.data['sender'];
            serverTime = message.data['messageTime'];
            print(serverTime);
//            final seconds = serverTime.seconds;
//            final nanoSeconds = serverTime.nanoseconds;
            DateTime timeDate = serverTime?.toDate() ?? null;
            final time = DateFormat.jm().format(timeDate);

            print(time);
            if (time != null) {
              final currentUser = loggedInUser.email;
              final messageBubble = MessageBubble(
                message: messageText,
                sender: sender,
                isMe: currentUser == sender,
                messageTime: time.toString(),
              );
              messageBubbles.add(messageBubble);
            }
          }
          return ListView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            reverse: true,
            children: messageBubbles,
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}

class MessageBubble extends StatelessWidget {
  MessageBubble({this.sender, this.message, this.isMe, this.messageTime});
  final String message;
  final String sender;
  final bool isMe;
  final String messageTime;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment:
          isMe ? CrossAxisAlignment.end : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: isMe
              ? EdgeInsets.only(
                  right: 20,
                )
              : EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: 20,
                ),
          child: Text(
            sender,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45),
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 10,
            vertical: 5,
          ),
          child: Material(
            borderRadius: isMe
                ? BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(20),
                  )
                : BorderRadius.only(
                    topRight: Radius.circular(20),
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(20),
                  ),
            elevation: 5,
            color: isMe ? Colors.lightBlueAccent : Colors.white,
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: 15,
                vertical: 15,
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    message,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    messageTime,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 10,
                      color: Colors.black54,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 10,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

and here is the error i am getting which vanishes after 1 sec.:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<QuerySnapshot, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>>#c7c89):
The getter 'hour' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: hour

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot> file:///J:/My%20Documents/flutter/flash-chat-flutter/lib/screens/chat_screen.dart:114:12
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
#1      _DateFormatPatternField.format1To12Hours (package:intl/src/intl/date_format_field.dart:507:22)
#2      _DateFormatPatternField.formatField (package:intl/src/intl/date_format_field.dart:357:16)
#3      _DateFormatPatternField.format (package:intl/src/intl/date_format_field.dart:244:12)
#4      DateFormat.format (package:intl/src/intl/date_format.dart:276:26)
...
```

Here is the snapshot of my data. It shows error though the data and everything is fine.

```
I/flutter (20608): {messageTime: Timestamp(seconds=1596923950, nanoseconds=769000000), sender: rony.yf25@gmail.com, text: rrr}
I/flutter (20608): {messageTime: Timestamp(seconds=1596919907, nanoseconds=674000000), sender: rony.yf25@gmail.com, text: tttt}
I/flutter (20608): {messageTime: Timestamp(seconds=1596919884, nanoseconds=184000000), sender: rony.yf25@gmail.com, text: hello}
I/flutter (20608): {messageTime: Timestamp(seconds=1596918220, nanoseconds=934000000), sender: rony.yf25@gmail.com, text: alsdifjalse}
I/flutter (20608): {messageTime: Timestamp(seconds=1596918137, nanoseconds=200000000), sender: rony.yf25@gmail.com, text: alsidfjasdf}
I/flutter (20608): {messageTime: Timestamp(seconds=1596918011, nanoseconds=857000000), sender: rony.yf25@gmail.com, text: slifdjai}
I/flutter (20608): {messageTime: Timestamp(seconds=1596917828, nanoseconds=410000000), sender: rony.yf25@gmail.com, text: sdlifa}
I/flutter (20608): {messageTime: Timestamp(seconds=1596917781, nanoseconds=912000000), sender: rony.yf25@gmail.com, text: dhalsid}
I/flutter (20608): {messageTime: Timestamp(seconds=1596917481, nanoseconds=457000000), sender: rony.yf25@gmail.com, text: alsidfjisd}
I/flutter (20608): {messageTime: Timestamp(seconds=1596917410, nanoseconds=747000000), sender: rony.yf25@gmail.com, text: alsiefj}
I/flutter (20608): {messageTime: Timestamp(seconds=1596917377, nanoseconds=497000000), sender: rony.yf25@gmail.com, text: hey}
I/flutter (20608): {messageTime: Timestamp(seconds=1596917078, nanoseconds=43000000), sender: rony.yf25@gmail.com, text: alisdjf}
I/flutter (20608): {messageTime: Timestamp(seconds=1596917009, nanoseconds=664000000), sender: rony.yf25@gmail.com, text: dlfjie}
I/flutter (20608): {messageTime: Timestamp(seconds=1596915940, nanoseconds=43000000), sender: rony.yf25@gmail.com, text: what the hell}
I/flutter (20608): {messageTime: Timestamp(seconds=1596915855, nanoseconds=204000000), sender: rony.yf25@gmail.com, text: hello}
I/flutter (20608): {messageTime: Timestamp(seconds=1596915359, nanoseconds=85000000), sender: rony.yf25@gmail.com, text: now?}
I/flutter (20608): {messageTime: Timestamp(seconds=1596915336, nanoseconds=709000000), sender: rony.yf25@gmail.com, text: what the hell?}
I/flutter (20608): {messageTime: Timestamp(seconds=1596915316, nanoseconds=263000000), sender: rony.yf25@gmail.com, text: sdlifj}
I/flutter (20608): {messageTime: Timestamp(seconds=1596915263, nanoseconds=685000000), sender: rony.yf25@gmail.com, text: sljeif}
I/flutter (20608): {messageTime: Timestamp(seconds=1596914949, nanoseconds=530000000), sender: rony.yf25@gmail.com, text: alsdifj}
I/flutter (20608): {messageTime: Timestamp(seconds=1596914912, nanoseconds=147000000), sender: rony.yf25@gmail.com, text: alkjsfdil}
I/flutter (20608): {messageTime: Timestamp(seconds=1596914381, nanoseconds=39000000), sender: rony.yf25@gmail.com, text: kdhsoi}
I/flutter (20608): {messageTime: Timestamp(seconds=1596914309, nanoseconds=901000000), sender: rony.yf25@gmail.com, text: sldkfjakljhf}
I/flutter (20608): {messageTime: Timestamp(seconds=1596914266, nanoseconds=63000000), sender: rony.yf25@gmail.com, text: soooo}
I/flutter (20608): {messageTime: Timestamp(seconds=1596914160, nanoseconds=123000000), sender: rony.yf25@gmail.com, text: hello again}
I/flutter (20608): {messageTime: Timestamp(seconds=1596914115, nanoseconds=909000000), sender: rony.yf25@gmail.com, text: hello}
I/flutter (20608): {messageTime: Timestamp(seconds=1596914034, nanoseconds=646000000), sender: rony.yf25@gmail.com, text: hello}
I/flutter (20608): {messageTime: Timestamp(seconds=1596913757, nanoseconds=969000000), sender: rony.yf25@gmail.com, text: hello again}
I/flutter (20608): {messageTime: Timestamp(seconds=1596913551, nanoseconds=830000000), sender: rony.yf25@gmail.com, text: hello}
```

Comment: seems `timeDate` is `null`

Comment: I printed to the console . But it did not show any null value.

Comment: Can you maybe provide the snapshot data which courses the error?

Comment: yes, I have posted the snapshot data. Kindly see this